# Can I make Workflow to select people without manual entry?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-manager, workflow-variable

For my workflow, I want to use the Action "Send Email" but as follows:

Column A holds the name of stakeholder
Column B holds the condition (a status of task)

I want workflow to Send Email to Column A if Column B's status is "No"

What I have been doing is writing "If/Else" and manually entering multi-layered parameters as this: 
    If Column A's value equals {Insert manually the name of a person}
    Then send email to {Insert manually the name of the person}
    Else
    If Column A's value equals {Insert manually name of the 2nd person}
    Then send email to {...2nd person}
    Else...

This is inefficient and I am exploring a better alternative as value of Column A can change depending on task assigned later. Thoughts?

Comment: Instead of adding manually you can create an User Group & send them email once. Also you can get the Display Name & Email ID of the users from User Profile.

Comment: Not sure how that would work to address each user for his/her specific assignment.

Comment: Are you talking that- you want to send the email o the basis of assigned task? I mean if a User A have assigned task then you have to send the email to both the assigner(Who is assigning the task) & A (Assigned user)?

Comment: So, I set Column A type to be People/person. So, when I click there, I can type in a name and SP will give me list to choose from and I select the name I need for that row. 

I want SP then to grab info from that column for each respective person. I am looking for a solution that's more like Send Email to "CurrentItem:ColumnA" than to manually select the person for that task. By asking SPD to automatically look through and select the person on its own, I want to have the freedom to change the person and not have to go back to workflow and manually select the new person each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question after researching different options as follows:

Step 1: Select Action "Send Email"

Step 2: click to edit the 'users' and click on the book icon of "To" field
[image]

Step 3: Choose "Workflow Lookup for a User..." and click on ADD
[image]

Step 4 and 5: From the "Lookup for Person or Group" window, choose the correct source in the source "Field from source"; in my case, the column titled "Dept. Stakeholder" Step 5: Choose "Return field as" field as 'Display Name' and click ok
[image]

End result should look like this:
[image]

The above steps created the correct algorithm engine to achieve my goal. In testing phase, I switched users for an assignment multiple times in the Column value in the Document Library. As long as the primary parameters to trigger the workflow met, SP activated the workflow and send out the email.